# Getting error in accepting nested JSON from stored procedure in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using Entity Framework to call a stored procedure. My stored procedure is creating JSON and I want to pass that JSON to Web API in the form of a string.

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateJson]
    @AppointmentID int,
    @JsonOutput nvarchar(max) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @JsonOutput = (SELECT TOP 1 AppointmentID, ReturnCode
                       FROM appointments
                       WHERE appointmentID = @AppointmentID
                       FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
    RETURN;
END
```

API entity class which accept string:

```
public partial class sp_test
{
    public string jsonOutput { get; set; }
}
```

API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<sp_test>>> Getsp_test(int AppointmentID)
{
    string StoredJson = "exec CreateJson " +
                        "@AppointmentID = " + AppointmentID;

    return await _context.sp_test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson).ToListAsync();
}
```

Error:

[image: This error]

Can I get some guidance on what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What about to substitute SET JsonOutput WITH SELECT @JsonOutput. See docs

Comment: Your procedure call doesn't match the procedure signature.

Comment: @RomanIeromenko okay let me try with that

Comment: I tried with this also string StoredJson = "declare @get nvarchar(max) exec CreateJson " +
                "@AppointmentID = " + AppointmentID+","+
                "@get output select @get"; . Not working

Comment: Procedure is not run at all due to the mismatch mentioned above. First decide which way you want to get data from sql server. Correct the proc and the calling code accordingly.

Comment: Better to avoid probable reserved words like get just in case

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: Or you can [edit] your question - that way we can read your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a result set compatible with the `sp_test` entity so that result set is consumable by `FromSqlRaw`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateJson]
    @AppointmentID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select (
       SELECT TOP 1 AppointmentID, ReturnCode 
       FROM appointments
       WHERE appointmentID = @AppointmentID
       FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) jsonOutput;
    RETURN;
END
```

Comment: @himanshu040 Note the seemingly superfluous use of a `SELECT (` subquery, this is needed because otherwise large JSON objects get broken up into separate rows

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @getJson nvarchar(max);
EXEC CreateJson
    @AppointmentIDr =  AppointmentID,
    @JsonOutput = @getJson OUTPUT
```